# yii2 migration generates createTable instead of addColumn

Tags: yii2, migration

I'm having trouble auto-creation migrations with bizley/yii2-migration-creator extensions on table updates. Initially, it works as expected with new tables:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

class m200122_110631_update_table_yii_urban_tourdate extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('{{%urban_tourdate}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'name' => $this->string()->notNull(),
            'time' => $this->dateTime(),
            'duration' => $this->integer(),
            'tour_id' => $this->integer(),
            'tourguide_id' => $this->integer(),
            'tourcourse_id' => $this->integer(),
            'start_station_id' => $this->integer(),
            'stop_station_id' => $this->integer(),
            'status' => $this->integer(3)->notNull(),
            'created_by' => $this->integer(),
            'updated_by' => $this->integer(),
            'created_at' => $this->integer(),
            'updated_at' => $this->integer(),
        ]);

    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('{{%urban_tourdate}}');
    }
}
```

Then after adding a column directly in database and creating another migration, I get a createTable statement as above (with the added column), which results in error (table already exists) when applying migration.

My expectation would have been to get only addColumn statement like this:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->addColumn('urban_tourdate', 'position', $this->integer());
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. yii migration/update table_name creates new migration with createTable command. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

```
yii migration/update urban_tourdate
```

the second time (not `create`).

Answer (score 0):

Too late answer but may help someone!
I had this problem too. Finally I fixed it by adding `'fixHistory' => true,` to configuration in console.php
Now my configuration looks like this:

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'migration' => [
        'class' => 'bizley\migration\controllers\MigrationController',
        'fixHistory' => true, 
    ],
],
```